# I got an error while tuning parameters in neural network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I'am tuning parameters for neural network
following is my code

```
layers = [[20], [40, 20], [45, 30, 15]] 
activations = ['sigmoid', 'relu']
neurons_params = [ 225,150,175]   
act_1_params=['tanh','sigmoid','relu']    
dropout_ratio_params=[0.18,0.30,0.23]
param_grid = dict(layers=layers, activation=activations, batch_size = [128, 256], epochs=[30])
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1,verbose=2)  
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

after few minutes i got following error

> RuntimeError: Cannot clone object
>
> as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter layers

Comment: Could you please add as much code as possible? I want to see the declaration / initialization of `activations` and `layers`.

Comment: I'am sorry @ShridharRKulkarni  here is the code
`layers = [[20], [40, 20], [45, 30, 15]]`     
`activations = ['sigmoid', 'relu']`   
`param_grid = dict(layers=layers, activation=activations, batch_size = [128, 256], epochs=[30])`     
`grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)`